# JAVA Move .JPG and .PDF Files to Specific Location

Tags: java, file, file-copying

I want to move `.pdf` files and `.jpg` files to specific folder and after that save the specific location path to database. so far with the help of google, i could able to copying file to new location (not moving) and saving the new path to the database as seen on below code sets.

```
try {
     JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
     choose.showOpenDialog(null);
     File f = choose.getSelectedFile();
     File sourceFile = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());
     File destinationFile = new File("D:\\" + sourceFile.getName());

     FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    int bufferSize;
    byte[] bufffer = new byte[512];
    while ((bufferSize = fileInputStream.read(bufffer)) > 0) {
       fileOutputStream.write(bufffer, 0, bufferSize);
       }

    fileInputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();

 } 
 catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What i want to know is

1. How to Move the files with a unique name instead of copying..?
2. How to show a message whether that file is being successfully moved
   or not in JOptionpane (because then only i can do inserting
   part)..?
3. How to retrieve those images link to open directly (like '*click
   here to open report*') and it should be open in computer's default
   image viewer or PDF viewer

Please help I'm tired of Googling for 2 and half weeks. thanks you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do, what you want:

- choose() limited to PDF and JPG
- move() file to destination
- open() with the default program

Added according the request in your comment:

- getFileExtension() get the String after the last dot
- generateDestinationPath() from today's timestamp + index + extension

The edited class:

```
    package testingThings;

    import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

    public class FileHandler {

        public Path choose() {
            JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
            choose.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF and JPG", "pdf", "jpg"));
            choose.showOpenDialog(null);

            Path sourcePath = choose.getSelectedFile().toPath();

            return sourcePath;
        }

        public void move(Path sourcePath, Path destinationPath) {
            try {
                Files.move(
                        sourcePath, 
                        destinationPath//, 
                        // since the destinationPath is unique, do not replace
    //                  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                        // works for moving file on the same drive 
                        //its basically a renaming of path
    //                  StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE
                );
    //          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file " + sourcePath.getFileName() + " moved");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, 
                        "moving failed for file: " + sourcePath.getFileName(),
                        "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
                );
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public void open(Path destinationPath) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(destinationPath.toFile());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, 
                        "file openning fails: " + destinationPath.getFileName(), 
                        "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
                );
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler();
            Path sourcePath = fileHandler.choose();

            String extension = fileHandler.getFileExtension(sourcePath);
            Path destinationPath = fileHandler.generateDestinationPath(extension);

            fileHandler.move(sourcePath, destinationPath);
            fileHandler.open(destinationPath);
        }

        /**
        * Generate a path for a file with given extension.
        * The Path ist hardcoded to the folder "D:\\documents\\". The filename is the current date with appended index. For Example: 
        * <ul>
        *   <li>D:\\documents\\2016-11-19__12-13-43__0.pdf</li>
        *   <li>D:\\documents\\2016-11-19__12-13-43__1.pdf</li>
        *   <li>D:\\documents\\2016-11-19__12-13-45__0.jpg</li>
        * </ul>
        * @param extension 
        * @return
        */
        public Path generateDestinationPath(String extension) {
            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss");

            String filename;
            Path destinationPath;
            int index = 0;

            do {
                filename = sdf.format(today) + "__" + index + "." + extension;
                destinationPath = Paths.get("D:\\documents\\" + filename);
                destinationPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ceo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\" + filename);
                System.out.println(destinationPath);
                index++;
            }
            while (destinationPath.toFile().exists());

            return destinationPath;
        }

        /**
        * Return the String after the last dot
        * @param path
        * @return String
        */
        public String getFileExtension(Path path) {
            String[] parts = path.toString().split("\\.");
            System.out.println(path);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
            System.out.println(parts.length);

            String extension = parts[parts.length - 1];
            return extension;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to give it a unique name..? (like img2016-09-13-55.jpg  and img2016-11-19-20-22.pdf)...?

because operator does not have to rename when he/she upload the document. if operator didn't upload without the unique name he/she would probably replace the document already in the database

Comment: your cording for moving file wasn't worked, then i removed `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` function. after that it worked. why is it happening like so..? without removing it i get an error says `java.nio.file.AtomicMoveNotSupportedException:`

Comment: @Henry i added new method for filename generation in the answer.

Comment: Atomic move works for moving file on the same drive. Its basically a renaming of path. By copying from D: to D: it should work. From C: to D: not.

Comment: Since the question is answered, please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left size of the answer.